# Are browser extensions inherently unsafe?

Tags: web-browser, virus, chrome

If we're doing sensitive things in the browser, like logging into cryptocurrency exchanges, is it too risky to have *any* browser extensions, for fear that there's a virus or something in them?

Comment: Extensions get the same access to the page the browser does ...

Comment: @schroeder So then the answer is that they are unsafe?

Comment: @fnavigate:  Not only the extensions are inherently  potentially unsafe but any software is, including the browser or the operating system.  One usually chooses which software to trust based on reputation of vendor and software - and the same should be done with browser extensions. Apart from that you can limit you risk by deliberately limiting the attack surface at the cost of usability, like starting sensitive tasks in another browser or browser profile or private browsing session with less extensions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Okay that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Comment: @fnavigate just as unsafe as using a browser in the first place: *that* could have viruses or bugs or do something malicious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser extensions have access to the pages you visit and so can read information and also insert JavaScript to send requests and the like. So yes extensions can be very dangerous. The other issue is that, like any software, it can be susceptible to supply chain attacks.

As a general rule, I advise people to use as few extensions as possible and only use trusted ones.

Answer (score 0):

As [Steffen says in the comments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/265245/are-browser-extensions-inherently-unsafe#comment549566_265245), browser extensions are software and, like all software, there's no such thing as "inherently safe" and you should only run ones you trust. In practice, extensions are sandboxed and thus often safer than "full trust" apps; if you run a non-sandboxed desktop process it can potentially interfere with / modify your browsers in a way that lets it track everything you do in them, but if you install a browser extension that is scoped to only getting page URLs every time you navigate or open a new tab, and only for the domain "zombo.com", then you're probably fine to do stuff on other sites no matter how malicious the extension is. Of course, you'd have to validate that the extension is actually restricted that way - its self-description can't be trusted, only its manifest and maybe the source of the extension (if it's something official like the Mozilla extension list) - and there's always some risk of a weakness in the extension sandbox or the rest of the browser that means the extension can get more privileges than it's supposed to have. Of course, lots of extensions' manifests specify that they can inject arbitrary script into pages and/or modify requests and responses, for all domains, and an extension like that has de facto full permissions to see everything you do an any webpage any time you use a browser where that extension is installed and enabled.

---

Since whether software is trustworthy is inherently a judgement call and everybody's judgement is fallible, it's generally best to limit your *attack surface* as much as possible. Use a fresh private browsing session so that there's no risk of other sites attacking your exchange site. Disable extensions in private browsing. Disable browser features you don't need. Make sure you don't have any untrusted software installed, and definitely not running. Heck, run it in a dedicated OS that you don't use for anything else. Maybe even use dedicated hardware that you don't use for anything else, eve. Use a dedicated app from your exchange rather than a browser (browsers inherently have a lot of attack surface; they're super complicated and by design load and execute code from arbitrary machines on the Internet)... as long as the dedicated app is actually more restrictive than a browser (some are just a wrapper around a browser, which is arguably worse!).

Obviously, not all of those mitigations are going to be viable for every scenario, and many will be overkill even if they're technically viable. There's also things you can do beyond attack surface minimization, like making sure the browser, OS, and any other running software are fully up-to-date and are currently-supported versions with no known unpatched vulnerabilities, enabling security monitoring (e.g. antivirus and IDS) and exploit mitigation controls (e.g. high-entropy ASLR and memory allocation canaries), manually verifying that the TLS certificate is the expected one (browsers don't support automatic certificate pinning but you can do it manually if you want), and physically securing your device and Internet connection. This kind of *defense in depth* can help mean that even if something related to your activity is compromised, you yourself might not be affected (or at worst you fail to complete the activity - denial of service - rather than giving the attacker any secrets or control).